# How to mark reminders as "Done" without going via Google Calendar?

Tags: google-now, google-calendar, google-assistant, reminders

I set reminders using Google / Google Now / Google Assistant (or whatever it's called these days). These reminders also appear (automatically) on my Google Calendar. All good.

However, when I receive a *notification* of this reminder I only get the options to "edit" or "delete" (even when clicking through to the reminder in the Google *App*). I don't want to "delete" it, as I want to keep a note of reminders I've "done" and besides I have several "recurring" reminders" that cannot simply be *deleted*. And I certainly don't want to edit it. I want to simply "Mark as Done", but how?

The only way to "Mark as Done" that I can see is to view the reminder in Google Calendar, when I get the single option to "Mark as Done". But going via "Google Calendar" requires additional (unnecessary) steps. Consequently, reminders often only get "Marked as Done" some days later then I see the entry is still showing in my Google Calendar.

So, in there a better/quicker way to mark reminders as "done" - preferably from the "notification" - without having to go via Calendar?

Answer (score 2):

I have recently discovered you can "Mark as Done" a reminder in the Google app by swiping right on the reminder itself:

[image: Swipe right to "Mark as Done"]

Note that this is only in the app, not on the *notification*.

HOWEVER, if you *swipe* a "recurring" reminder to "Mark as Done", it will mark all future reminders as done also! This is certainly a problem for me, as I have several recurring reminders and I only want to mark the "current" one as done.

[image: End repeating reminder]